# How to mock members of started services created by ServiceTestRule?

Tags: android, mockito, android-service, android-espresso, android-testing

To simplify my question: I have a `Service` that is invoked by `startService` (rather then `bindService`), does some calculation and publishes a method to some other component when it finishes.

I want to test its behavior. I have a Test class with a `ServiceTestRule` and a test method that starts the service using:

```
serviceRule.startService(
  new Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext(), MyService.class));
```

I would like to add something like this:

```
mockedPublisher = Mockito.mock(Publisher.class)  // Publisher is a member in MyService
service.setPublisher(mockedPublisher)
verify(mockedPublisher).publish(eq(correctResult))
```

But not quote sure where (in the `@Test` method or `@Before`?) and how to get the instance of the service itself in order to mock methods or inject mocked objects.

I saw some (very few) examples of how to use `ServiceTestRule` but they all focus on binding services which are easier because you have a 'service object' in hand that you can at least mock or verify. With `startService` I seem to have no affect on how the service in created and can't alter it.

Any help?